# How to plot only when is in London and New York sessions

Tags: pine-script

How to show the fractal only when is in London or New York session?

That's how I'm showing the fractal

plotshape(filteredtopf, title='Top Fractals', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.white, 0), offset=-2, display = display.all - display.price_scale - display.status_line)

That's what I tried

session_time = input.session("1200-1500", "Session")
is_in_session = time(timeframe.period, session_time + ":1234567")

if is_in_session
plotshape(filteredtopf, title='Top Fractals', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.white, 0), offset=-2, display = display.all - display.price_scale - display.status_line)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time()` and pass your session strings to it to figure out if your are in a given session. Then simply `and` them.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

london_sess = input.session("0700-1600", "London")
newyork_sess = input.session("1300-2200", "New York")

is_in_london = time(timeframe.period, london_sess)
is_in_newyork = time(timeframe.period, newyork_sess)
is_in_both = is_in_london and is_in_newyork

bgcolor(is_in_london ? color.new(color.white, 85) : na)
bgcolor(is_in_newyork ? color.new(color.yellow, 85) : na)
bgcolor(is_in_both ? color.new(color.green, 85) : na)
```

Background color is white when in London session and yellow when in New York session. It will be green if the current bar is in both sessions.

[image]

Comment: Code part:

if confirmed_fractal  == true
    filteredtopf := barstate.isconfirmed and isBWFractal(1)
    filteredbotf := barstate.isconfirmed and isBWFractal(-1)

plotshape(filteredtopf, title='Top Fractals', style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.white, 0), offset=-2, display = display.all - display.price_scale - display.status_line)
plotshape(filteredbotf, title='Bottom Fractals', style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.white, 0), offset=-2, display = display.all - display.price_scale - display.status_line)